# Python Class Attributes default

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

```
class A():
    count = 0
    print(count)
    def __init__(self):
        A.count+=1
    def exclaim(self):
        print("I'm an A")
    @classmethod
    def kids(cls):
        print("A has", cls.count,"little objects.")
```

My question is that I create a object with "t1=A()". And A.count should be 1. I understand. And then, if I create second object with "t2=A()". I don't understand why A.count = 2. I thought when used A(), it will make count back to default 0.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I forget to add “A.count+=1”

Answer (score 0):

In `A`, `count` is a class variable, meaning there is one copy of the variable for the class.  Instances of the class continue to pick up that value.

In `__init__`, you have `A.count += 1`.  This modifies the class variable directly, without creating an instance variable.  So there's still only one copy of `count`, and all instances pick up the current value.

If you instead change it to `self.count += 1`, then you'll get the behavior you expect.  Initially, each instance will pick up the value from the class.  But when `self.count += 1` is executed, it will add 1 to `count` and then store the result in an instance variable that is private to the instance.  Thereafter, the instance will have its own copy of `count` which is independent from the class variable, or the instance variables in other instances of the class.